# Python Boto3 put_object file from lambda in s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I would like to send a json file in s3 from a lambda. I saw in the documentation that we can send with the function boto3 **put_object** a file or a bytes object (Body=b'bytes'|file).

But if I'm not wrong, if I send a file in s3 with Body=bytes and then I download my file the content will be not visible.

So in my lambda function, I receive messages from a SQS Queue, I created a file with the message content in the lambda temporary folder /tmp. And I want to get this json file to send it in my_bucket/folder/file.json

I saw many examples to create a file in s3 but Body parameter is in bytes and not a file.

This is my code (python3.7)

```
def alpaca_consent_customer_dev(event, context):  # handler
    # TODO implement
    request_id = context.aws_request_id
    print('START - RequestID: {}'.format(request_id))

    # function to write json file
    def write_json(target_path, target_file, data):
        if not os.path.exists(target_path):
            try:
                os.makedirs(target_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                raise
        with open(os.path.join(target_path, target_file), 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)

    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-west-2")

        request_id = context.aws_request_id
        print('START - RequestID: {}'.format(request_id))
        
         # Get message from SQS queue
        for record in event['Records']:

            data = record
            
            # Get message from SQS
            data_loaded = json.loads(data['body'])

            sns_message_id = data_loaded['MessageId']

            print('data loaded type:', type(data_loaded))

            data_saved = json.dumps(data_loaded)

            # Create json file in temporary folder
            write_json('/tmp', sns_message_id+'.json', data_saved)

            # Check if file exists
            print(glob.glob("/tmp/*.json"))
            # result: ['/tmp/3bb1c0bc-68d5-5c4d-b827-021301.json']


            s3.put_object(Body='/tmp/'+sns_message_id + '.json', Bucket='mybucket', Key='my_sub_bucket/' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')+ '/'+ sns_message_id + '.json')
    
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('ERROR lambda failed: {}'.format(str(e)))
```

Thanks for your help. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [official example in the boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.10.46/guide/s3-uploading-files.html):

```py
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

You can just use the `upload_file` [method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.10.46/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) of the s3 client.

Comment: NOTE: Here `file_name` is a string containing file address of your file like ```"home/user/documents/project/saves/summary.json"```